# Sitecore - multi site have rendering use a dynamic datasource location

Tags: sitecore

I have inherited a sitecore installation that has the following tree

```
\sitecore
  \content
    \websitehome
    \Component Content
        \Rich Text
```

I am now looking to create a second site, but this second site needs it own copy of the components folder

So I have created a structure similar to

```
\sitecore
  \content
    \websitehome
    \Component Content
        \Rich Text
    \newsite
      \Home
      \Component Content
        \Rich Text
```

I have a rendering, where the datasource location is currently hardcoded to
\sitecore\content\Component Content\Rich Text

I have been looking to modify this so that the rendering's data source location uses a query, and have found the following links as references:

- http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-rendering-datasource-locations/
- https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/19/multiple-datasource-locations-to-single-sublayout-or-rendering-in-sitecore/
- https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/site-relative-datasource-locations

So I have created the following query:
query:ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='{71443FD6-55D4-42BC-B762-80A00BC8B2D2}'] /..//Component Content/Rich Text

{71443FD6-55D4-42BC-B762-80A00BC8B2D2} is the home page template id that is used by \sitecore\content\websitehome, and \sitecore\content\newsite\home

I have used the old sitecore xpath builder to verify that the query does work.

The problem is that with the above query, when the "Select the Associated Content" dialog is displayed, it is not filtered to the correct path, but to the sitecore root.

I have no idea what is wrong and as to why the query is not being executed correctly.

The solution is using sitecore 8.2 update 2.